# pre_get_posts with tax_query causes empty result

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pre-get-posts, custom-post-type-archives, tax-query

I need to adjust the main loop for all archive pages in the following way.
I have registered a custom taxonomy "myposttypes". Every single post is assigned to exactly one term of "myposttypes".

If it is a category or tag archive page, only posts with "myposttypes->term1" should be included into the query result.

If it is a custom taxonomy archive page only posts with "myposttypes->term2" should be included into the query result.

I've already implemented the corresponsing `pre_get_posts` hook but **I'm not getting any results at all for all my archive pages.** I have plenty of posts with corresponding taxonomies in my blog instance so there should be results.

Here is my approach:

```
function wpmw_adjust_archive_queries( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( is_category() || is_tag() ) $term_slug  = 'term1';
        if ( is_tax( 'beitragsarten', 'news' ) ) $term_slug = 'term2';

        $taxquery = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'myposttypes',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $term_slug
                ),
            ),
        );

        $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpmw_adjust_archive_queries' );
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is my adjusted and simplified approach, that still does not work unfortunately. I get an empty result. I var_dump'ed $query and tax_query seems to be added correctly to query_vars.

```
function wpmw_adjust_archive_queries( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' ) ? : array();

        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'myposttypes',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'term1' ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        );

        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpmw_adjust_archive_queries' );
```

Here is the corresponding part of $query

```
[tax_query] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => myposttypes
                            [field] => slug
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => term1
                                )

                            [operator] => IN
                        )

                )
```

Comment: On the category archive, should the category be ignored?

Comment: No, the category should be considered on category archive. Basically it should be the standard loop with a kind of "filter" that only posts with myposttypes->term1 are allowed

Comment: So be very careful not to override the default tax_query - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `tax_query` incorrectly. Take a look at [Codex Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

`tax_query` should be an array which can contain:

- `relation` - it should be string (AND/OR)
- taxonomy term - array with defined taxonomy, field, terms, and so on.

In your code your setting `tax_query` to:

```
$taxquery = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'myposttypes',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term_slug
        ),
     ),
);
```

And it should be:

```
$taxquery = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'myposttypes',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $term_slug
    ),
);
```

`post_type` is another param, so you can't set it inside `tax_query`.

But... You still should be careful, if you change `tax_query` - it may have a value already. So if you want to be respectful of that, you should use something like this:

```
$tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' );
if ( ! is_array( $tax_query ) ) {
    $tax_query = array();
}
$taxquery[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'myposttypes',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => $term_slug
);
$query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
```

This way you will add your tax query to already existing queries and not override them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The 'post_type' => 'post' is a copy/paste error. I deleted this line from my initial post.

Comment: Hope it helps - and if so, remember to mark it as correct answer, so site stays tidy...

Comment: I still have the same problem after having applied your proposed code.
When I var_dump $query the is TWO times tax_query:
1.) $query->query_vars['tax_query']
2.) $query->tax_query['queries']

Do I need to adjust both of them?

Comment: No, that's normal - one thing is query var called `tax_query` and the other one is parsed `tax_query` object.

Comment: Which one of these I need to manipulate in pre_get_posts? You proposed code adds [tax_query] into [query_vars]. Unfortunately my result is still empty.

Comment: @EmWe only query_vars using set and get methods.

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I was looking for. I found a second "pre_get_posts" hook, that was causing this error. Thank you for you help.

Comment: @EmWe No problem :)